# URL for creating local repository on Subversion

Tags: svn, subversive

I want to create a new Subversion repository through Aptana Studio. Both Aptana SVN plugin and Aptana Subversive plugins are installed. I am not following what URL to give as I want to create the repository on localhost.

Please see this link: http://screencast.com/t/qVn3OvWqL

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You must create the repository *before* you can checkout from it. This is a mdifference to DVCSes. So to create. Usually Plugins are not able to *create* repositories(as you need local access to server).

If you have TortoiseSVN just browse to the directory where your repository should be, in your case:

```
d:\subversionrepository\prazact_website
```

If you use TortoiseSVN:

```
right click on folder "prazact_website"  -> "TortoiseSVN" -> "create Repository here"
```

If you use Commandline:

```
svnadmin create d:\subversionrepository\prazact_website
```

If you created the repository, you can now connect with the above mentioned URL:

```
file:///d:/subversionrepository/prazact_website
```

Answer (score 14):

Normally this is where you provide the url via which other clients (including yours) can access this repository. 
SVN repositories can be accessed via various access protocols:

1. svn (svn://)
2. http (http://)
3. local file access protocol (file:///)

If you have a central repository location where all your repo's are located, and you want to create your repo in the same location, then you can click on the browse button. It will help you see the repository root used by your SVN administrator. 
BUt if this is a private repository and you want to create it on your own local host, try the file:/// protocol.The way to specify is this -  file:///d:/mysvndir/rohit_repo

Comment: OK - Looks like the module ra_local is not installed on your host. Have you configured the host in question to act as a subversion server? If you have, you should see this module running when you type in "svn --version" command on your command line.The module ra_local is essential to create/access local repositories and in your case it looks like you dont have a subversion server configured and ready. You may want to read the svn book here for details: svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/… (there is perhaps a more recent version of this documentation )

Comment: up vote for mentioning the file:///. I've downloaded an old repository to my local machine so I can view ancient history. Don't need anything except blame...

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and found that the version of the svn connector DOES matter.

On my Mac it meant going into `Eclipse > Preferences > Team > SVN`

And then inside of the "SVN Connector" tab I selected the "***SVNKit 1.3.5 r7406 (for SVN 1.6.15, all platforms)***" connector and hit "apply".

This fixed it for me, by default it was on the *SVN 1.5.6 version* which if you just installed SVN you are likely not on that older branch/release.

Make sure the connector version matches the version of SVN you have installed.